# Let $W=\{p(B):p\text{ be a polynomial with real coefiicient}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W=\{p(B):p\text{ be a polynomial with real coefiicient}\}$ and where $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$  Then the dimension $d$ of the space $W$ satisfies

1.$4\le d\le 6$

2.$6\le d\le 9$

3.$3\le d\le 8$

4.$3\le d\le 4$

I have calculated that $B^3=I$ so $I,B,B^2$ will be the basis vebtors in $W$ so I hope $\dim=3$ but I dont know why they have put bounds, It was question in an past examination.

Comment: For a duplicate question, I find this a particularly weird one in its formulation. Regardless of the actual value found for $d$ (except for $d=9$), there will fail to be a unique answer matching it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $B^k=B^{k-3}=B^{a}$ for some $a\in\{0,1,2\}$ and for all $k>3,k\in \mathbb{N}$.

This implies that any higher power of $B$ can ultimately transformed to a power $\in \{0,1,2\}$. So your claim follows.

Comment: I guess yes, both the options are correct.